# Element wise multiplication of every row/column of a matrix with a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix, named as p_c_w having dimensions 6X7599 and the other matrix named as p_w having dimensions 1X7599. I wish to have their element-wise multiplication but I am unable to do that. For size of rows of p_c_w and columns of p_w to be same, I have taken transpose of p_c_w and stored it in anss. Error I am receving is: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Code is below. Can anyone please help?

Thanks a lot in advance

```
anss=p_c_w'
for i=1:size(anss,1)
for j=1:size(p_w,2)
    temp(j,i)=anss(i,j).*p_w(j);   
end
end
```

Comment: use `p_w(1,j)` instead of `p_w(j)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [**`bsxfun`**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5;
      1 2 3 4 5;
      1 2 3 4 5 ];

B = [ 1 10 100 1000 10000];

C = bsxfun(@times,A,B)
```

returns:

```
C =

           1          20         300        4000       50000
           1          20         300        4000       50000
           1          20         300        4000       50000
```

Works the same for `A'` with `B'`

---

so for your case:

```
temp = bsxfun(@times,p_c_w,p_w)
```

Comment: Thanks @thewaywewalk

It has worked now using bsxfun :)

Answer (score 0):

From R2016b release, you do not need to use bsxfun for this operation. For example, the following code will do the same thing as @thewaywewalk's answer.

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5;
      1 2 3 4 5;
      1 2 3 4 5 ];

B = [ 1 10 100 1000 10000];

C = A.*B
```

Check out [doc for implicit expansions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).